# Angular active component with *ngIf when Module is programmatically lazy loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular-components, angular-module

I have a situation in which I have to load a lot of component in a page (call it `parent page`) of a specific route in my application, but all components are handled by a logic with *ngIf that let me to show and hide them.

For example:

```html
<div *ngIf="active_slot_one"> <component-one></component-one> </div>
<div *ngIf="active_slot_two"> <component-two></component-two> </div>
<div *ngIf="active_slot_three"> <component-three></component-three> </div>
<div *ngIf="active_slot_four"> <component-four></component-four> </div>
```

These components are imported each from a different library that I have created. So in the module of parent page I have to import all modules that declare and export the components from my libraries.
Now I would to import that module in lazy mode, so I try to import the needed module only right before the corresponding variable `active_slot_`**x** became `true` using these function:

```js
loadModule(value: boolean, module: string) {
    switch(module) {
        case 'one': 
            !!value && (await import('lib-one').then(m => m.LibOneModule));  // line that I inserted to lazy load module
            this.active_slot_one = value;
        case other_case:
            // same before
    }
}
```

with this function I active and deactive the correct components. Removing all import from my  parent page module and adding the line with the comment before I active the ngIf I expect that the component load correctly.
Indeed the main.js when I compile my app the main.js is smaller than before and module one appears in the Lazy Chunk Files

[image]

At the same time the module are imported exactly when I need

[image]

but when the ngIf is activated the component isn't shown in my page

What am I doing wrong?

----- **OTHER INFO** -----
By statically importing module_one into the parent page module when the ngIf is activate I can see the slot with the component inside and appear the little arrow that tells me that there is something else inside the component:

[image]

Otherwise, with lazy loading using the upper function, the dom always show correctly the slot with the component inside but the component seems to be empty:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you show where do you use the "loadModule" function?

As far as I know, you may need to set up a kind of provider in the component you are trying to use it.

Another solution to it might be to inject the components in the position from the component, appending it after the component first initialized.

In another words, it seems that the life cycle hook in misundertood

Comment: The loadModule function is called inside a custom event handled with observable that activate the ngIf variables with a logic.

Comment: Essentially there might be a case in which a specific slot (with its component inside) will never be activated and in this case I don't want his module to be loaded anyway.

Comment: Did you try to use the change detector to enforce a refresh?